# injecting an $element in angular-ui router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm trying to get access to the dom element ($element) from the controller, but get an 'unknown provider' error (Unknown provider: $elementProvider <- $element)

Here's the code:

```
 CatalogController = function($scope, $state,$http,$element) {
    console.log('CatalogController',$scope.$id,'parent:',$scope.$parent.$id);

}
appModule.config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('catalog1', {
        url: '/catalog',
        views: {
            'catview':{
                templateUrl: 'partials/catalog.html',
                controller: [        '$scope', '$state','$http','$element',CatalogController ]
            }
        }
    });
})
```

The injection of $http is fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why? This breaks all AngularJS conventions

Comment: Lior, there is no `$element` service to inject.

Comment: thanks @ProLoser and Stewie. why injecting $element would break them? on the directive doc (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) it says "The controller is injectable with the following locals:... $element.." and indeed it has worked on my previous directives.

Comment: @Stewie can i specify an '$element' service? any other way? I need access to my DOM element inside the controller. maybe I should ask, how does it work on 'regular' directives

Comment: Lior, there's a not so slight difference between [application Controllers](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.mvc.understanding_controller) and [directive controller](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). By the look of your question it seems to me that you are confusing these two. Although you wouldn't be the first.

Comment: @Stewie thanks, seems this indeed is the issue. The controller that i can use is an Application controller. any ideas on how I can make a directive controller for the ui-router?

Comment: @ProLoser (or whoever) no need to downgrade my question, i would never, never think of breaking ANY conventions. on coding, religion, manners or anywhere! ;)

Comment: @Lior There's no such thing as a directive controller "for" anything other than for a directive. The conversation has strayed a bit; to get back to a more productive discussion, can you tell us what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks @JoshDavidMiller! I'm trying to use ui-router from Angular-UI. this amazing hierarchical state-machine/ router system has a way to define a (1) view and (2) controller for every state. however, the controller cannot be injected with the $element of the view... here's the docs https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router. looking at the code, it seems they are building a directive dynamically for every view.

Comment: Okay, I see. When developing with AngularJS, we care very much about separation of concerns; one of the rules to help us here is "No DOM manipulation outside of a directive". Controllers for a route or ngController are just glue between services, the view, and the directives. You should *never* try to manipulate the DOM in them, so asking for `$element` means you're doing it wrong. :-) This is where ProLoser and Stewie were coming from. So what are you wanting to do with `$element` more specifically?

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller I need to animate the view by attaching/removing CSS classes on the element. And I was able to do it when I built my own directives... Look on the directive doc (docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)  - it says "The controller is injectable with the following locals:... $element..". it seems its allowed there, on the 'directive controller'

Comment: What you want to do is create a directive that can do this for you and then attach that directive onto the right DOM node. A directive controller controls a piece of the view; a regular controller controls your model and passes info to the view. And never the two shall mix. Again, what you **never** want to do is mix view and model logic. Injecting `$element` into the controller of your route does just that. You said you had it working in a directive before; why can't you use that directive now?

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller I didnt mean to use the 'regular controller' for DOM manipulation. I can use that directive I already built now, that's an option. But, i'd like to use the views that the state manager dynamically creates for me, just have them use my owned supplied 'directive controllers'. I'm actually trying to change the ui-router now for that, still no success

Comment: Sorry, I'm not being clear. So here it is: you **cannot** pass a directive controller or a directive to a route; what you are trying to do cannot be done. Directives should **only** be applied **directly** to a view. E.g. if your directive is called `myFadeDir`, you need to have something like this somewhere: `<div my-fade-dir>`. Directives are the only things that should manipulate the DOM (except in some advanced corner cases) and directives are only applied in the view. The router has nothing to do with what you're trying to do.

Comment: hi @JoshDavidMiller please see answer below

Comment: hi @ProLoser and everyone, please see answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm glad to announce that the folks at ui-router accepted my change/pull request as well as my explanations for the reason. injection of an element and attr is officially supported: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/tree/master/src

I'd like to thank everyone who's been involved in this lively discussion

EDIT: more than a year later, it seems that it was accepted: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1657

Comment: This was done prematurely and without consensus. There is now discussion regarding reverting this change: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/71

Instead, it may be preferred to look at the new ng-animate directive and review how it integrates with ng-view. Instead, a ticket on ui-view should be opened to request for integration with ng-animate.

Comment: @ProLoser - more than a year later, it seems that it was accepted: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1657

Comment: Regardless, without knowing more about what you were trying to accomplish I still feel like this is a sign of bad design. The ultimate question is WHY do you care about that DOM element from inside the controller.